# How to switch between different content on my js dropdown/showcontent box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a JS Fiddle. I'm aware my drop down content isn't working there but it appears fine on file so I'm assuming it's just some code missing in the JSFiddle which is causing it not to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/akgfxrue/

HTML CODE

```
   <div id="links"> <span class="circles"><a href="#!" id="wilfconnect" onclick="show_content()">&#128279;</a></span>

    <br>    <span class="circles"><a href="#" >&#128241;</a></span>
    <span class="circles"><a href="#">&#8505;</a></span>
    <a id="drop" onclick="show_content()"><img src="images/drop.png" alt="drop" style="width:345px;height:290px"/></a>

      <!-- everything in the bananas div drops beneath the 'drop' image upon click -->

    <div id="bananas">
        <div class="dropcontent">
            <ul class="dropcontent">
                <li>bananas bananas bananas bananas</li>
                <li>bananas bananas bananas bananas</li>
                <li>bananas bananas bananas bananasbananas.</li>
                <li>bananas bananas bananas bananas</li>
                <li>bananas bananas bananas bananas</li>
            </ul>
            <img class="promo" src="promo.png" alt="Promotion" style="width:30%;height:auto"></img>
            <br>    <span class="talk" a href="how.html">FOR MORE DETAILS CLICK HERE</span>
                <!-- I want to be able to have the dropdown appear with different content if one of the other buttons is clicked i.e. a similar div called 'apples' and one called 'oranges' -->

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS CODE

```
 #links {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #E04E39;
}
#links .circles {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 70px;
    bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-family:"entypo";
    font-size: 40pt;
    text-align: center;
    color: #E04E39;
    border-radius: 150px;
    background: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 700;
}
/* I don't need the background image or css styling changing, I merely need the content changing such as the list items and the promo image */
#bananas {
    position: relative;
    transition: height 0.6s ease-out 0s;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0em;
    background-image: url("hidden_bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
ul.dropcontent {
    float: left;
    font-family:"Thonburi";
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-: 20px;
    padding: 200px auto;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
li.dropcontent {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.dropcontent {
    width: 60%;
    float: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.promo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: auto;
}
img.promo {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 8%;
    top: 5%;
    padding: 0;
}
.talk {
    position: absolute;
    left: 62%;
    bottom: 10%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #E04E39;
    padding: 7px 7px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS CODE

```
    function show_content() {
    var s = document.getElementById("bananas");
    s.style.height = "290px";
}
```

Anyway, I currently have this code working within my homepage. You'll notice this content drop down is full browser width and utilises a background image. In the drop down is a bullet list, promo image floated to the right and a link to show more details.

I only have the code working with one lot of content at the moment (bannanas div) and I'd like to be able to add two more, near identical content areas that appear instead dependent on which button is clicked.

Currently there is only one active button (the big image). Clicking this reveals the content below but I want it to show content related to the link that is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I understand to an extent I can get this working with simple one word content but haven't found anything for a slightly more complex content dropdown using the JS code I'm currently working with.

Side note, I've also not managed to find a way to hide said content as of yet using my current code. Any tips on this would be great too of course.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wait, if the fiddle isn't working, it's too vague for anyone else to understand the problem. if you want people to help you faster, try making it work so more people will be interested in your problem

Comment: I'm still fairly new and struggling to see why it wouldn't work within the fiddle. I can try uploading a screenshot if that helps? If not, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSFiddle wasn't working because the function was not available when the DOM elements have loaded. I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akgfxrue/3/) fixing that issue (moved function definition to [jquery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)) and also included code to toggle between two similar lists (bananas and bananas1).

Below is how toggling is done, first time bananas div will be displayed, from the second time bananas and bananas1 will be displayed alternatively

```
show_content = function () {
    var s = document.getElementById("bananas");
    var s1 = document.getElementById("bananas1");

    if (s.style.height != "290px") {
        s.style.height = "290px";
        s1.style.height = "0px";
    } else {
        s.style.height = "0px";
        s1.style.height = "290px";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use jquery, why aren't you implementing it to `document.getElementById("bananas")`? and also `s.style.height = "290px"`. is there a reason?

Comment: I just updated OPs JSFiddle, otherwise I would have gone with jQuery methods to update them! _ah! call me lazy!_ :P

Comment: just saying, OP never requested a jquery answer

Comment: This seems to almost get the job done perfectly. I'm wondering how I drop down the 'bananas1' content upon clicking on a different button/link though? In this version it only shows bananas1 upon clicking the same link again. So imagine there was a bananas button and a bananas 2 button.

Thanks for all the help though, it's already gave me a much better understanding of it!

Comment: To do this on click of a different button, create a new function `show_content_bananas1` and move the code inside `if` part on to the function. Also, if need be, make sure you hide any other divs (bananas) that are already visible (like using `s.style.height = "0px"`).

Comment: @jjk_charles which is not ideal if you have 100 buttons

Comment: It is a decision OP has to make if the buttons are going to be more in number. In such a case he needs to write a generic function and accept the element/selector as argument and show/hide contents accordingly.

Comment: Hi jjk_charles. There's only 3 buttons. I've better illustrated them using your method here: http://jsfiddle.net/8hscfmb0/1/

It works great, the issue that is arising as you may notice is that multiple content dropdowns can be open at the same time when there should only ever be one content dropdown/div that is visible/active.

I'm not sure if this issue is related, I'm assuming it is, but this is causing each drop down content to fall lower than the previous contentdiv. 

By clicking 'B' dropdown starts just beneath the circles, clicking 'C' dropdown starts a few lines down from the circles.

Comment: @AdamR this is what I mentioned in my earlier comments (// make sure you hide any other divs (bananas) that are already visible (like using s.style.height = "0px") //). Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hscfmb0/2/) with the show/hide fixed.

Comment: Where does that styling go in the JS? It's already used within the if and else functions on your JSFiddle.

Perhaps it's the div creating a border/margin?

Comment: I found the issue with them not dropping in the same position.
I had 'margin-bottom: 20px;' on the #bananas, #bananas1; CSS. Removing this has fixed the issue. I can't thankyou enough for your help. This was causing me great headaches but now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** use `onclick="function()"` in js, because:

1. if script loads faster than the content, it will fail
2. untidy and harder to organize
3. reasons, reasons, reasons, too many to say, you can google it.

http://jsfiddle.net/xzgv6va3/

What I changed is deleted the `onclick` attribute and used an event listener, so the script can work anywhere. Using the logic on if the dropdown's height is matched, toggles the dropdown.(it would be better if you can use the class to compare though)

Also, you had an error on this line, so here's the correction:

```
<span class="talk" href="">FOR MORE DETAILS CLICK HERE</span>
```

(There's an extra `a`)

### The Fix:

```
function showContent() {
    if (this.nextElementSibling.className == "dropdown") {
        var s = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (s.style.height == "290px") {
            s.style.height = "0px"
        } else {
            for(var i=0;i<dropdowns.length;i++){
                dropdowns[i].style.height = "0px"
            }
            s.style.height = "290px"
        }
    } else {
      return false  
    }
}
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");

for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++){
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', showContent, false);
}
```

### To add more dropdowns:

Add a dropdown button and the dropdown immediately after. Here's the minimal template:

```
<a class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown Button</a>
<div class="dropdown">
    Content
</div>
```

**There is no requirement on id attributes**

**Please feel free to ask for explainations**

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look into this in the morning. Using the other method puts each dropdown content slightly below the other, as if they're taking up height when hidden.

Anyway, thanks again. I'll respond with how I get on in the morning.

Comment: I've had a look at this, it works better in the sense it hides the other content that is visible before dropping down the new content.

However, it creates a similar problem. If you check out

http://jsfiddle.net/xzgv6va3/

I've tried to make it clearer. The 3 circles will be used as buttons to show/hide the content. There will only ever be 3. So baring in mind the position of the circles, I need the content to drop down from the exact same position for each dropdown (they currently drop down slightly below the previous one). 

I'm going to look through it, see if I can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: glad that you went through this problem